# Why is the 2nd row of my 2d array taking random values from RAM?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

so I'm working on this project for class, and I'm trying to assign values to a 2d array using a for loop, but I've run into a couple problems. Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

const int MAX = 10;

int main()
{

    int matrix2[MAX][MAX];
    int matrix1[MAX][MAX];


      int i, j;

      j=0;
    for (i=0; i < MAX; i++){

        matrix1[i][j] = i + 5;

        for (j=1; j < MAX; j++){
            matrix1[i][j] = matrix1[i][j-1] + 4;

            cout << matrix1[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }




}
```

And this is what it outputs:

```
9 13 17 21 25 29 33 37 41 
1422620036 1422620040 1422620044 1422620048 1422620052 1422620056 1422620060 1422620064 1422620068 
10 14 18 22 26 30 34 38 42 
11 15 19 23 27 31 35 39 43 
12 16 20 24 28 32 36 40 44 
13 17 21 25 29 33 37 41 45 
14 18 22 26 30 34 38 42 46 
15 19 23 27 31 35 39 43 47 
16 20 24 28 32 36 40 44 48 
17 21 25 29 33 37 41 45 49
```

and this is the output I'm trying to get:

```
5   9   13  17  21  25  29  33  37  41  
6   10  14  18  22  26  30  34  38  42  
7   11  15  19  23  27  31  35  39  43  
8   12  16  20  24  28  32  36  40  44  
9   13  17  21  25  29  33  37  41  45  
10  14  18  22  26  30  34  38  42  46  
11  15  19  23  27  31  35  39  43  47  
12  16  20  24  28  32  36  40  44  48  
13  17  21  25  29  33  37  41  45  49  
14  18  22  26  30  34  38  42  46  50
```

I'm asking if someone what I can do to fix the second row, and also why the first column isn't printing

Comment: Try changing `matrix1[i][j] = i + 5;` -> `matrix1[i][0] = i + 5;`  `j` never gets reset and second time round the `i` loop `j` will be `MAX` when the above assignment happens.

Comment: move j = 0 inside the `i` loop at the beginning

Answer (score 4):

`j` is `0` only for the first "`i` iteration"; in all the other cases it is `MAX`.
In the cases where it is `MAX`, `matrix[i][j]` has undefined behaviour.

The robust solution is to use your loop variables for looping and nothing else.
Declare everything in as small a scope as possible.

```
for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++){
    matrix1[i][0] = i + 5;
    for (int j = 1; j < MAX; j++){
        matrix1[i][j] = matrix1[i][j-1] + 4;
        cout << matrix1[i][j] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

the problem is that `j` is not reset in time, so at the line `matrix1[i][j] = i + 5;` j is past the end of the array. Move setting `j` to zero forward a line

```
for (i=0; i < MAX; i++){
    j = 0;

    matrix1[i][j] = i + 5;

    for (j=1; j < MAX; j++){
        matrix1[i][j] = matrix1[i][j-1] + 4;

        cout << matrix1[i][j] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

or change `matrix1[i][j] = i + 5;` to `matrix1[i][0] = i + 5;` as Richard Critten suggested

Answer (score 0):

Your reset of j should be inside the loop. In the second round (i=1), j starts as MAX.

```
for (i=0; i < MAX; i++){
  j=0;
```